# Posting data to php file

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have the following variable in Javascript. I want to know how to pass this data to a PHP  so that I can display the contents of the data once redirected.

```
    postData = {
        'dates_ranges': datesAndRanges,
        'action':'build',
        'output_type': output_type,
        'form_html': formHtml,
        'width': formBuilder.width(),
        'rules':validationRules,
        'theme': theme,
    };
```

Comment: Have you done some research before posting your question?

Comment: As for me, I don't really understood the question.

Comment: The same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210025/pass-data-from-jquery-to-php-for-an-ajax-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery [post method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to pass data to PHP file:

```
$.post("/path/to/script.php", postData, function(result) {
    // work with result
});
```

In PHP use $_POST global to get the variables:

```
print $_POST['dates_ranges'];
print $_POST['action'];
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery it goes easy & clean like this:

```
$.post('script.php', postData, function(response){ 
    // process/display the server response 
});
```

Comment: There is no need to serialize `postData`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$.post("YOUR_URL", postData, function(response) {
    // handle with response
});
```

**OR:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: YOUR_URL,
  data: postData,
  type: 'post',
  success: function(response) {
    // handle with response
  }
});
```

And In your PHP file:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
   $d = $_POST;
   echo $d['date_range']; // and so more
}
```