# How to pass the ajax post request from one server to another server using jquery with php?

Tags: ajax, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass data from jQuery to PHP for an ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210025/pass-data-from-jquery-to-php-for-an-ajax-post)

How do i pass the values from one server to another server using ajax,jquery

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/url/on/other_server',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: '{"key":"value"}',
    success: function(data, status) {
       console.log(status);
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, error) {
       console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Is there need any other external .js file.

Comment: How does it pass values from one server to another? It sends a request from your browser to the server

Comment: This code would work as long as you have jquery included on the page

Comment: If you're looking to go to an outside server you'll run into cross-domain request restrictions. In which case you'll need to look into JSONP

Comment: Thanks Addam Hardy. its work for me.Once again thanks for your great help.