# displaying results of php quiz without page reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

This is a simple one, but I just can't figure it out.

I have a simple form:

```
<form action='#' method="post">

    <label for="question-1">Question One</label>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" value="2" />

    <label for="question-2">Question Two</label>

    <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" value="2" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" class="submit"/>

</form>
```

Then I have simple php in `results.php` to calculate the results:

```
<?php

$answer1 = $_POST['question-1-answers'];
$answer2 = $_POST['question-2-answers'];

    $result = 0;

     $a =array( 0=> "$answer1", 1=> "$answer2"); 

    $result = array_sum($a)/count(array_filter($a));
    echo "Your score is: "; echo round($result, 1); 
?>
```

This all works great, but I want the result to show up on the same page as the quiz when the user presses the submit button, without a page reload. I know I need to use jQuery, but everywhere I look has a different way of doing it, and nothing works.

Edit:

So I added the following:

```
 $function() {
   $.get('../results.php', function(data) {
   $('.result').html(data);
   alert('Load was performed.');
    });
}
```

and

```
<div class="result">The results are:</div>
```

and updated the submit button with `<input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" class="submit" onclick="function()"/>`

I'm still not getting anything when I click the submit button, and when I check the console the only error I get is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` but I don't know where I have an extra {.

Comment: You need AJAX you definitely don't need jQuery.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use jQuery to load a PHP quiz result HTML page. You then want to inject it into the dom.

Include jQuery, and then this example should work, assuming quiz result page is at (php/quizResult.php) - you can set this up as you like

jQuery

```
$.get('php/quizResult.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

Put the jQuery in a function in JavaScript, and call it when you want to load the results.

Comment: Come on people, stop -1ing posts that will contain more information shortly... This is a common thing on Stack... Anyway I've included example code now...

Comment: I updated my question with more questions  after trying your suggestions.

Comment: Hey @Arel I don't think you should name it function(), javascript will kill you for using a keyword in a function name! name it something like getResults().

Comment: Also, you probably want to pass some data to the results... You can do this using json encode, which will encode your data into a bit of text your server side code can parse! Next, it will return some json with data for the page to display, and you can load up a template for displaying the data! If you'd like more of a tutorial on how to do this, open up a chat with me and we'll talk.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to figure this out. How do I open a chat?

Comment: I've opened up a chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25319/question-answering-chat

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example as Christian has hinted at:

```
$.post('/callcenter/admin/postContacts', data, function(returnedData) {
    // do something here with the returnedData
    console.log(returnedData);
});
```

Your PHP page would then return JSON.

Ref.  [Pass data from jQuery to PHP for an ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210025/pass-data-from-jquery-to-php-for-an-ajax-post)