# Haveing one drop down selection box populate another from Mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I realise this is a popular topic and I have read though several examples but for some reason I cant get my AJAX code to load the second php page that will trigger the creation of the second drop down menu. I am using a test page called (page2.php) to try and debug this without the rest of my website getting in the way.

The page code is shown below.

```
<?php   include("db_connect.php"); 

$query = 'SELECT * FROM db_class_catagories';
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnection,$query);
?>

<select id="primary_catagory" name="primary_catagory" onchange = "getData(this)"style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;width:315px;height:20px;z-index:11;text-align:left;">
<option value=''>Select</option>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo "<option value='" . $row['primary_catagory'] . "'>" . $row['primary_catagory'] . "  
</option>";}
?>
</select>

<div id="get_catagory"></div>

<script>
function getData(dropdown) {
    var catagory = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    var dataString = "primary_catagory="+catagory;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_sub_catagory.php", // Name of the php files
    data: dataString,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $("#get_catagory").html(html);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

by use of alert I have determined that the drop down selection is at least reaching the function, but my AJAX code wont forward it on to the php page correctly.

the php page to generate the second drop down list is called get_sub_catagories.php and contains the following.

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");
if ($_POST) {
    $primary_catagory = $_POST['primary_catagory'];
    if ($primary_catagory != '') {
       $query = "SELECT * FROM db_class_catagories WHERE primary_catagory=" . $primary_catagory;
       $result1 = mysqli_query($dbconnection,$query);

       echo "<select name='state'>";
       echo "<option value=''>Select</option>"; 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
          echo "<option value='" . $row['sub_catagory'] . "'>" . $row['sub_catagory'] . "    
</option>";}
       echo "</select>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  '';
    }
}
?>
```

The function is being called but no data is being passed to the get_sub_catagories.php page. Im sure ive just got a location messed up somewhere but im not solid on AJAX and using this as my tutorial.

I think its this part

```
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#get_catagory").html(html);
```

But im not sure what's wrong.

Thanks for any pointers here!

UPDATE:

Ive solved the first part of the issue here, It never occured to my to load a JQuery Library which I have now done with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This now returns the drop down list object but its not populated, BUT the query is being shown in debug (SELECT * FROM db_class_catagories WHERE primary_catagory=Electronics)

Comment: a quick thought: you can use the network (filter to only XHR) tab in the Chrome developer tools to debug ajax calls.  the headers tab shows the variables that were passed through GET and POST, the preview and response tabs show the response in various formats.  This will tell you if the ajax call got the right parameters and returned anything.

Comment: This error appeared when I did as you suggested, Ive revisited the code but cant see my own mistake.. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Could jquery not be loading on the server and thus unable to locate itself?

Comment: the <script> tags are being processed by the browser not the php engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suspect that it may be how you are using data parameter.  have a look at [Pass data from jQuery to PHP for an ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210025/pass-data-from-jquery-to-php-for-an-ajax-post).

try something like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_sub_catagory.php", // Name of the php files
    data: {'primary_catagory': dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value},
    success: function(html)
    {
        $("#get_catagory").html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: This didn't seem to have any notable effect, I know its a sill question but does the (html) and html.(html) in that section play a significant role? all the pages are php, in truth I don't full understand this code yet, until I get this version working I cant expand it to fit its final purpose!

Comment: what are you seeing in the XHR view of the chrome developer tools?  is the page being loaded?  is there a response coming back ?

Comment: I found the problem, I never realised that I needed to load a jQuery Library to use AJAX! once I loaded that on the page all your script alterations took effect! cheers!