# how to retrieve ajax data in "multiple" drop box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 2 multiple select drop box.. form one I want to inflate the other multiple select drop box.. can anyone help me with this?
When I get result from the jQuery or ajax i want that result to display in 2nd number multiple select drop box...

this is my ajax..

```
function demo1() {
    var emp_id = document.getElementById("employeeName").value;
    alert(emp_id);
    var datastring = "emp_id=" + emp_id;
    //alert (emp_id);



    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search_emp.php",
        data: datastring,
        dataType: "text",
        //async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#clname").append(data);
            $('#clname').html(data);
            //document.getElementById("clname").innerHTML=data;            
        }
    });
}
```

This are 2 multiple drop box..

```
 <label>Select Employee </label>
     <select multiple="multiple" class="w300" name="employeeName[]" id="employeeName" >

 <?php $result = $conn->query("SELECT id,first_name,last_name,employee_id FROM employees");
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['id']; ?><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>
                    <?php echo $row['last_name'] ?></option>

                <?php } ?>
 <!--<?php echo $option;?>-->
<!--<?php echo $option2;?>-->
 </select>
 </br>
 <label>Select Client</label>
 <select multiple="multiple" class="w300" name="clname[]" id="clname">


 <!--<?php echo $c;?>-->
 </select>
```

Comment: May be this could help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210025/pass-data-from-jquery-to-php-for-an-ajax-post

Comment: not the thing i want still thanks..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html()` will set the `innerHTML` content of a DOM element, you can't do that on a `<select>`. There are two ways to solve it:

**1) Quick & dirty: replace HTML**

Make your `search_emp.php` also return the HTML code for the `<select>`, like this:

```
echo '<select multiple="multiple" class="w300" name="clname[]" id="clname">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['gn_id'].'">'.$row['gamename'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Then you can use  `jQuery.replaceWith()` to replace the whole DOM element:

```
$('#clname').replaceWith(data);
```

**2) Much nicer: Build DOM from JSON**

Instead of returning HTML code, your `search_emp.php` should return JSON, something like

```
[
    {
        "gn_id": "123",
        "gamename": "superduper client"
    },
    {
        "gn_id": "234",
        "gamename": "another client"
    }
]
```

You can easily do this by passing the client array to [PHP's json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and add a JSON content type header (Note that you will have to change the `dataType` attribute of `$.ajax` to "json" or you could use the shortcut function `$.json()`:

```
// identify the content as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// put your MySQL query here.
// if errors occur, send a HTTP 500 header and return a useful error message as JSON

// collect results in an array
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// return the results as a JSON list
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Before you make the AJAX call, you would want to remove all existing options from the select. In the success function of the AJAX call, you can loop through the results and append them to the select:

```
// reset the select options
$('#clname').empty();

// make the ajax call
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search_emp.php",
    data: datastring,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        // build the options from the JSON data
        for (let client of data) {
            $('#clname').append('<option value="' + client.gn_id + '">' + client.gamename + '</option>');
        }         
    },
    // optional, but good to have: error handling
    error: function (data) {
        alert("An error occurred:\n" + data.error)
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn0rgmm5/)

Note: `let client of data` only works in modern browsers (ES2015 compatible). If you want to support older browsers, do an old-fashioned `for (len=data.length, i=0; i<len; ++i)` loop. Or use `jQuery.each()` (although this might be slower)

Comment: hey...Thanks for help..M getting the html code like this..while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['gn_id'].'">'.$row['gamename'].'</option>''';
  
    }      Do i have to change in this?

Comment: well thanks again...and that code worked but thing is that thing printing that result next to the drop box not in the drop box..what can i do for that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "next to the drop box". Sounds a bit like a problem with your styling. I added a fiddle to show how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/jn0rgmm5/

Comment: see it's like from multiple drop box m sending multiple data at one time..let's consider m sending 2 selected items into ajax then serialize that array then at php side I use implode and by "IN ({$id})" m getting multiple data..now this data I need to set it again back into that other multiple drop down...by the 1st method which is replace it does not include the style and cc i use other wise it working fine..and by jason.. i m getting the data back on main server if i use "ALERT" function i can see that data in [object] : [object] format but  not able to receive into that multiple dropbox..

Comment: Just want to ask one more thing as a beginner I don't know if this really works or not but can we save that ajax result into one string or array then at the multiple drop down we can echo that string?

Comment: "it does not include the style and cc i use": If you are missing a class or something, just add it to the select. "i can see that data in [object] : [object] format": JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation", so of course it's an object. `alert()` can only display strings. if you do a `console.log(data)`, you will see the object's contents in the console. If you use JSON, you can loop over the result with `for` and append the options to the select with a direct DOM manipulation. The whole idea of this approach is _not_ to build a HTML string but letting the browser build the DOM.

Comment: ohhh ok thanks for that and appreciate..:) i will use console.log(data) from now:D and yes it was not working because of css's style..